# Output MySql table to Console Output

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c++11

Is there a way to display a MySql table to the standard console with only its name and without creating a new file? I already have the path, I just don't know how to display this table. It's referred to as SQL_TABLE_NAME in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this anyway related to C++?

Comment: Can you share your code please? It's hard to help you without the details.

Comment: If you already have the table name, use `cout` to display the name.  No new file necessary; no paths required.  Example:  `cout << SQL_TABLE_NAME << endl;`.

Comment: This capability is also available with the `mysqladmin` utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=fred7 --password=OpenSesame DBName < "/fullpath/myScript.sql"
```

write a select statement inside myScript.sql

you can output to a txt file too with `> outFile.txt`